# Extract arrays and nested arrays within a json file, using serde format in AWS Athena

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am extracting data one by one in an array and nested array but I want to extract all data from an array with one statement like a 'SELECT *'
this is what it looks like:

[image]

Instead of writing

```
customerdata.data.balances[8].data.balances[2].date date_29,
customerdata.data.balances[8].data.balances[3].date date_29
```

etc

I am wondering is there a way to get all values from .data.balances array e.g .data.balances[*]

Comment: Can you please add real data example and desired output?

Comment: desired output is to get all values within
customerdata.data.balances[8].data.balances
I have tried
json_extract_scalar(customerdata, '$.data.balances.date')
but I got syntax error within athena

Comment: At the moment I am extracting nested array[2],[3] etc and creating a view to use with other json files but if the next json file has only one nested array or 20 I need a statement that will get them all instead of the specific number of arrays

Comment: It would be great if you could provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) representing the issue. Also AFAIK you can't access json data by field name (i.e. `customerdata.data`) so I would say `customerdata` is not actually json type but some other.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your actual data type is but you can try using unnest for every layer of nested data. Something like this:

```sql
WITH dataset (id, nested) AS (
    VALUES (
            1,
            CAST(
                ROW(
                    1,
                    ARRAY [ 
                        ROW(11, ARRAY [ ROW(111, '1') ]),
                        ROW(12, ARRAY [ ROW(121, '2') ]) 
                    ]
                ) as ROW(id INTEGER, data ARRAY(ROW(id INTEGER, data ARRAY(ROW (id INTEGER, str VARCHAR)))))
            )
        )
)

SELECT id, t.row.id nested_id, tt.row.id as double_nested_id, tt.row.str
FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(nested.data) AS t (row)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.row.data) AS tt (row);
```

Output:

| id | nested_id | double_nested_id | str |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 121 | 2 |

note that exploding data this way can have some perfromance implication.

Comment: I am trying to use this understanding 
SELECT id, t.row.id nested_id, tt.row.id as double_nested_id, tt.row.str
FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(nested.data) AS t (row)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.row.data) AS tt (row);

of the second cross join unnest.  To unnest further down the tree

SELECT
  balances.month.yearnumber
, balances.month.monthnumber
, moreBalance.balances.date
FROM 
  athena_data
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(customerdata.data.balances) t (balances)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(balances.data) AS tt (moreBalance);

Comment: @SidHowes not sure what your problem is. In the example query I unnest first level into `t` with one column `row` and then unnest the second level (`t.row.data`)

Comment: yes I have used your suggestion but within Athena I am getting an error
and thank you for your help on this

Comment: @SidHowes the code in the provided answer was run against the Athena. Can you please provide actual query and actual error you are facing (as text, not images).

Comment: Also please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)