# How to query wrap multiple cross join unnest in one statement

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, cross-join, unnest

I want to unnest the tree branches further with multiple cross join unnest but not sure on the syntax
here is what I have so far:

[image]

```sql
SELECT balances.month.yearnumber, balances.month.monthnumber
FROM athena_data     
CROSS JOIN unnest(customerdata.data.balances) t (balances)
```

I want to unnest further such as balances.data.balances.DATE
but in athena it will not let me unnest more than 3 branches

Comment: Do not post code as images.

Comment: ah apologies fairly new to this

    `SELECT
    balances.month.yearnumber,
    balances.month.monthnumber
    FROM 
    athena_data
    cross join unnest(customerdata.data.balances) t (balances)`

Comment: Also I would say that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69825335/2501279) provides enough information about how you can flatten nested data.